# how to remove a navigation controller with a view

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios4

I have a tabbar application with a navigation bar. For one of the actions I am instantiating a navigation controller programatically and adding a view with tableview. I want to remove this navigation bar and tableview programatically clicking a button on the new navigation bar. how to do this ?

I tried popview but it is not poping out.

Comment: I don't understand your question well. You mean you have a button and you want when user click on it, you remove the navigation bar

Comment: yes. on clicking the button on the navigation bar, the tableview and navigation bar should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

To hide it

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

If you have added a UINavigationController on top of another UIViewController, then from the uiNaviagation controller, you will not be able to remove the navigation bar even if you remove the current view, and all the subview. (the parent uiviewcontroller also get the nav bar)

One way to fix this is, access the app delegate, and remove the top view from the window before 
adding the UINavigationController

```
AppDelegate *dg = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
NSArray *ar = [[dg window] subviews];
//then remove all the views in ar
//then add uinavcontroller
[[dg window] addSubView:[uinavcontroller view]];
```

then add UINavigationController, when you want to replace the UInavigationcontroller with the first UiViewController. do the similar steps like above.